# Get the row that got error while bulk data updating in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Suppose we have 10 row in the table variable `@tblMessageDetails`. If anyone of them failed, I need to get the failed row full data separately.

The purpose of this is to suppose one row failed and I need to process the other 9 after removing the error one.

```
UPDATE tblDelivery  
SET ArrivedDateTime = CONVERT(datetime, M.ArrivedDateTime, 113),MessageDetails=MessageDetails1
FROM tblDelivery    
INNER JOIN @tblMessageDetails M ON M.PKDelivery = tblDelivery.PKDelivery
```

Does anyone know how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Isdate()` Function to filter the bad records. Try this.

```
UPDATE tblDelivery
SET    ArrivedDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME, M.ArrivedDateTime, 113)
FROM   tblDelivery
       INNER JOIN (SELECT ArrivedDateTime,
                          PKDelivery
                   FROM   @tblMessageDetails
                   WHERE  Isdate(ArrivedDateTime) = 1) M
               ON M.PKDelivery = tblDelivery.PKDelivery
```

Comment: This is not what I looking for, suppose we have another fields other than ArrivedDateTime  in the SET .Then your suggestion will fail.

Comment: @ArunKumar - then add that column in filter.